# Java server communication with clients

Tags: java, sockets

So currently my ServerSocket looks like this

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server(9008);
    }
}

public class Server {

    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket client;
    private ArrayList<ClientConnection> clientList;

    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            // Create out server with our desired port
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            // Server started, let the user know
            System.out.println("Server started at port " + port + "...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Unable to start server, print error
            System.out.println("Unable to start server on port " + port + "...");
        } 
        // Start our main server method
        runServer();
    }

    public void runServer() {
        clientList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Wait for new clients and accept them
                client = server.accept();
                // Let the user know - print
                System.out.println("New user connected - " + client.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress());
                // Start thread for our client
                ClientConnection getClient = new ClientConnection(client);
                clientList.add(getClient);
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(getClient);
                clientThread.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ClientConnection implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;

    public ClientConnection(Socket client) {
        // Set client socket
        this.socket = client;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // Read from our client input
            BufferedReader readClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = readClient.readLine()) != null) {
                // Print client message
                System.out.println("Client says - " + line);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, client connects, sends some data and server reads it, but my question is
How can I send a message from my server to all the clients? Im currently saving the clients on a ArrayList so I can just loop that ArrayList open a writer and flush it but I want to send the data I get on my ClientConnection class

How should I handle this code? everything done on server class? or..?

Comment: Your clients are not aware of each other.  Why would you want to handle broadcast from a client side?

Comment: ClientConnection is part of the server, when a client connects the server makes a new thread for it where it listens to client messages, I dont know how to send that messages to my server class where the client list is located

Comment: Do you want to broadcast your message only when one of the clients request it?

Comment: Its for a online chat, when a client sends a message to the server, send that message to the rest of the clients or even to all clients

Answer (score 0):

Not to be too much specific, but you should probably look around the observer pattern.

When a new client connects to the server and you create the `ClientConnection` instance, it can be observable and observed by another class that handle messages. This way, when a client send a message and the `ClientConnection` handles it, it automatically transmits it to the class that handles the messaging feature and that is aware of all the connections, and then this class transmit the message to all the clients.

1. Make ClientConnection implements Observable interface (or extend the Observable class for a more convenient usage)
2. Make `Server` implements the Observer interface, so that it can observe observables.
3. When a client connects, create a new `ClientConnection` and make the `Server` listens to it (`addObserver()`)
4. When a client sends a new message, make `ClientConnection` perform `setChanged()` and `notifyObservers`
5. This way the `Server` get noticed (via `update` methods that it should implement) of the new message and which `ClientConnection` sent it.
6. The `Server` now iterates through all its client and send the message to each of them

See [Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) and [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html), that should be sufficient enough. If not, there is a whole bunch of articles about the observer pattern on the web.